# Calculate the difference b/w two months data

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a mysql table orders in that I have a column order_date which is current time stamp(2016-08-17 00:00:00.000000). now I want to select or count the data's entered this month and the previous month, after this I can find the difference between these two months I am using this code and it is not working.

```
    $sql="SELECT * FROM order WHERE order_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $result;
```

this is not working an mysql error is produced.

Comment: Try CURDATE() instead of NOW()

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version@AmirKhan

Comment: Not working@mishanon

Comment: `order` is a keyword, you cannot use it as a table name

Comment: That was the problem thanks bro@wau

Answer (score 0):

First, the following is the correct logic to get all values from the current month and all of the previous month:

```
select *
from orders o
where order_date >= date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate) - 1 day), interval 1 month);
```

Then, use conditional aggregation for comparison.  Here is an easy way:

```
select sum(month(order_date) = month(curdate())) as cur_month,
       sum(month(order_date) <> month(curdate())) as prev_month,
       (sum(month(order_date) = month(curdate())) -
        sum(month(order_date) <> month(curdate()))
       ) as diff
from orders o
where order_date >= date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate) - 1 day), interval 1 month);
```

Note:  I don't fully see the utility of comparing a partial month (this month) to a full month (last month), but that is what you seem to be asking for.  If you are asking for something different, then ask *another* question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Why all this codes saying You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM order WHERE DATE(order_date) LIKE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)";
$result = $this->db->query($sql);
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this Link[http://sqlhints.com/2015/07/10/how-to-get-difference-between-two-dates-in-years-months-and-days-in-sql-server/] will help you

Comment: [Link](http://sqlhints.com/2015/07/10/how-to-get-difference-between-two-dates-in-years-months-and-days-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this. Hope it helps what you want. Thanks

```
   $todayDate = date('Y-m-d');
   $todayMonth = date("m", strtotime($todayDate ));
   $previousMonth = $todayMonth - 1;

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM order WHERE MONTH(order_date) BETWEEN '$todayMonth' AND '$previousMonth'";
```